Vim tabularize align discarding comments line
In my Verilog instantiations I am currently using the following format:
spi_mst_if #(

   .D_W(D_W)

) i_spi (
// System interface
   // -- inputs
   .SClk   (SClk),
   .Reset_n(Reset_n),
   .SyncRst(SyncRst),
   .CfgCPol(CfgCPol),
   .CfgCPha(CfgCPha),
   // Data interface
   // Chip select
   .Cs(Cs),
   // Master Output slave input
   .Mosi(Mosi),
   // Master input slave output
   .Miso(Miso)
);

for which I use the following function to align on character (:
function! AlignIoInstance() range
   
   silent! :'<,'>v/\/\//Tab /(/l0
   silent! :'<,'>v/\/\//s/\s*)/)/g
   silent! ;'<,'>v/\/\//s/\s\+$//g

endfunction

snoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> <M-i> <C-o>:call AlignIoInstance()<CR>
xnoremap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> <M-i> :call AlignIoInstance()<CR>

Is it possible to align relative to the rightmost column match of '(' along all the line range using an appropriate regex?
For example, I would like to obtain the following result:
spi_mst_if #(

   .D_W(D_W)

) i_spi (
   // System interface
   // -- inputs
   .SClk   (SClk),
   .Reset_n(Reset_n),
   .SyncRst(SyncRst),
   .CfgCPol(CfgCPol),
   .CfgCPha(CfgCPha),
   // Data interface
   // Chip select
   .Cs     (Cs),
   // Master Output slave input
   .Mosi   (Mosi),
   // Master input slave output
   .Miso   (Miso)
);

and I have to admit regexs are not my best...

You could be interested to the vim-easy-align plugin
With that plugin installed you could:

Select the range of line you would like to reformat
Run the command :'<,'>EasyAlign /(/ {'lm':0,'rm':0}


It does exactly what I want. I am giving it a try. Thanks!

Thanks for the feedback! If the answer solves your problem we recommend to accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Works like a charm! =)
